# Was Sati (a hindu custom) a rule during Shivaji's tenure?

Tags: history, customs, kings, sati

I want to know : To whom was it mandatory to perform sati during shivaji's rule- only kshatriya widows? or all widows irrespective of castes?

Comment: I think it has always been based upon choice, instead of a rule. During Mahabharata, Satyawati, Ambika, Ambalika, Kunti did not perform Sati, but Madri did.

Comment: @V.Aggarwal, yes Sati is voluntary. Shastras do not mandate it. But it is not prohibited either. Great rewards are mentioned in afterlife/other-planets where wife & her husband live together happily.